# Transfering data from an activity to a fragment on a button click

Tags: android

I want to transfer data from an activity with edit texts to a fragment class with a list to only display the edit_name box. I want to be able to click a button in the activity class and for it to save all of the information and display only the edit_name box. Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could use Intents to do this, here is an example :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12739968/5552022

Otherwise, you could use a library like EventBus which handles the process pretty efficiently :

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

```
                // Create a new Intent object as container for the result
                final Intent data = new Intent();

                // Add the required data to be returned to the MainActivity
                data.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, "Some interesting data!");

                // Set the resultCode as Activity.RESULT_OK to 
                // indicate a success and attach the Intent
                // which contains our result data
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data); 

                // With finish() we close the DetailActivity to 
                // return back to MainActivity
                finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tranfer your data via bundle:

From your activity use below code to addd data in bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "your string");
// set Fragmentclass data as fragment arguments
YourFragment fobj = new YourFragment();
fobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment you can get your data:

```
String strtext = getArguments().getString("key");
```